# How to change clearcase_albd account domain name and password using batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, clearcase

We are in the ClearCase windows domain migration phase. Now we migrated the domain but how to change clearcase_albd account domain name and password using batch script in user machine. I'm very new to batch scripting.

```
Old Domain Name: Old_Domain
New Domain Name: New_Domain

Old Account: dragon
New Account: dragon_fire
```

Comment: Are you talking about changing the account used for the albd service? (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146207) (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21177467)

Comment: Depending on your ClearCase version, this might help: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0703_nellis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the users have admin access to the machines, a user executed batch file likely won't work.

You may have better luck using the `SC` command to do it remotely. You'll also need to change the ClearCase admin group name.

If you're going to directly access each of the user systems, you can create a `.reg` file to reset the group name stored in `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Atria\ClearCase\currentversion\ClearCaseGroupName`.

The service name and password changes are simple:

```
SC config albd obj= (new domain)\(new account) 
SC config albd password= (new password)
```

You will also need to remove all the locally hosted views if the old owning accounts will no longer be in use.
If you haven't gotten to that part of the migration yet, you can use the `-replace_server_process_group` option in [`cleartool fix_prot`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/r_tshoot_acls_fix_prot.htm) to change that.
If you use `fix_prot -root` to change view storage permissions, you may render the view unable to access some elements.

Comment: @VonC How to encrypt the password in batch script ?? I don't want to disclose the password with users.

Comment: @Yashwanth -- If you use SC to remotely change passwords, you don't need to encrypt anything. If you need to scramble passwords, things get a little more difficult since you can't exactly hide the password from anyone who can ru the script. You may have to create an executable to reset the password, and have it either us an internally hardcoded password (bad idea) or descramble a file.